# How to mock database in flutter

Tags: flutter, mockito, sqflite

I tried to mock database to test my local api, i search in official document finding mockito which can work with remote api fine, but also can not work with local database out of box, is there any way to work around of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In these cases, you have two options (among many others). Even if my examples assume you're making HTTP calls, it doesn't matter. You can use these strategies regardless the specific use case I'm exposing!

---

The first one is using the "Strategy pattern" to create an interface for the API and then switch between a test and a production API. Here's a simple example:

```
abstract class HttpRepository {
  const HttpRepository();

  Future<Something> sendRequest();
}
```

You can now create 2 concrete classes: one is for the actual API call and the other is just a mock for tests.

```
/// Use this in your tests
class MockHttpRepository extends HttpRepository {
  const MockHttpRepository();

  @override
  Future<Something> sendRequest() async {
    // Simulating the HTTP call
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    return Something();
  }
}

/// Use this in your Flutter code to make the actual HTTP call or whatever else
class ApiHttpRepository extends HttpRepository {
  const ApiHttpRepository();

  @override
  Future<Something> sendRequest() async {
    // Doing a real HTTP call
    final response = await makeGetOrPost();
    return Something.withData(response);
  }
}
```

In this way, you'll use `ApiHttpRepository` in your Flutter app and `MockHttpRepository` in tests. Use `const` constructors whenever possible.

---

The other way is using mocks to simulate fake HTTP calls or anything else. Basically, you're using `when` to "trap" a method call and return a fake response you can control.

```
// 1. "Enable" mocking on your type
class MockRepo extends Mock implements ApiHttpRepository {}

// 2. Mock methods
const ApiHttpRepository repo = MockRepo();
when(repo.sendRequest()).thenAnswer((_) async => Something());
```

In this case, we're using `thenAnswer` because the return type of `sendRequest()` is of type `Future<T>`. In your case, if you are reading data from a database you just need to:

1. Make your class "mockable" using `extends Mock implements YourClass`
2. Use `when` on the mockable instance and control the output

Make sure to use `thenAnswer` if the method returns a `Future<T>` and `thenReturn` in all the other cases.

Comment: How is this answer accepted? The OP asked about moking a database not the Remote Api... smh